# How to obtain text logged into a file in java

Tags: java

This might be a weird question, but I really don't know how to ask it.  I want to get any information logged into a file and make it accessible (e.x - a program logs into the file, and I get that value as a String in my project).

Comment: I was afraid to continue reading after "This might be a weird question, but I really don't know how to ask it."  lolz

Comment: Can you please provide more details, and any code that you have tried?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  You probably want to search Google for something like "java read input from file", try something, and come back with a more specific question when you get stuck.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Using java.util.Scanner, you can read a txt file and add it's contents to a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  File source = new File("filename.txt");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
  String myString = "";
  while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    myString = scanner.nextLine() + " ";
  }
    scanner.close()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about what you want to do? If you just need to read the log file then you can use Reader/Writer API in java to read/write text files.

Use BufferedReader class, which has readLine() method to read entire line at once. Sample program to read a file using [BufferedReader class](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)